# How to list all js files loaded by a website using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to check a website for specific .js files and image files as part of a regular configuration management check.  I am using python and selenium.  My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#import modules required for the test to run
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Start headless browser
web = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
web.start()
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1024,768)
#Navigate to the current URL
browser.get("https://XXXXXXXX")
time.sleep(2)

page = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'script')

for i in page:
    print(i)
for j in page:
    print(j.text)

browser.quit()
web.stop
```

The array returned contains entries like

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="238c4f20-f995-11e6-9445-570b2cf065ee", element=":wdc:1487832970059")>
```

which I get when I try print the array entries.  I assume these are the files referenced with the script tag that I have found.  I cannot access them in any way to check if the file name or path is correct.

Any advice on how to do this?

Thanks
Rudi

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
for i in page:
    print(i.get_attribute('src'))
```

This should print `JavaScript` file name like `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`

Also you should note that some `<script>` tags could contain just `JavaScript` code, but not reference to remote file. If you want to get this code you need `i.get_attribute('textContent')`

**Update**

If you want to get scripts from `iframe` also, try:

```
for frame in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe'):
    browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
    for i in browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'script'):  
        print(i.get_attribute('src'))
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: While this does help in identifying some of the scripts on the page, there are others that are tagged by <script id="XXXX" src="YYYY.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.  I cannot find those ones.  Is it perhaps related to the orginal "find_elements" code, in that I am not finding all the scripts i am looking for ?

Comment: These tags could be generated dynamically. Just `import time` and add `time.sleep(3)` after  `browser.get("https://XXXXXXXX")` to wait 3 seconds until tags generated

Comment: I had a sleep(2) already in the code, i extended it to sleep(5) but the output remains partial.  All scripts that are tagged with an ID (as in  <script id="XXXX" src="YYYY.js" type="text/javascript"></script> are not returned by the find_elements instruction.  I suspect I need to find them in another way, due to the id="XXXX" bit, but do not know what it is.

Comment: No, attribute `id` doesn't affect on the way you getting required element... But you might check whether `scripts` that weren't found located inside an `<iframe>`.

Comment: They may be in an iframe.  If this were the case, how would I handle it?

Comment: Try code from updated answer and add it to existed code

Comment: I tried the code.  It looks like there are no scripts in the only iframe on the page.  Another possibility. the command browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'script') does not find the scripts with the id="XXXX" tag as this value gets concatenated with the scripts tag as in "scripts#XXXX" (It appears this way when viewing the site in browser dev tools).  The problem is the id values are dynamic, change on each page load.  I suspect I need to use a regex or something dynamic in the  browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'script') instruction, in place of the 'script' string, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using phantomJS, why not use its scripts to capture these data. You can use `netlog.js` to capture all network data loaded for a given page in HAR format. Later use a `python-HAR parser` to list down all your .js or img files.

command line:

```
phantomjs --cookies-file=/tmp/foo netlog.js https://google.com
```

[netlog.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netlog.js)
[Har Parser for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haralyzer/1.4.10)

Comment: I tried the netlog.js from the command line with phantomjs.  Again the output remains partial. All scripts that are tagged with an ID (as in <script id="XXXX" src="YYYY.js" type="text/javascript"></script> are not returned by all scripts tagged without it are returned.  So is there another way to return scripts that include the "id="XXXX" bit?

Comment: I am afraid your point is not clear to me. Does all the js entries get stored in the HAR file that you generated using netlog.js ? Or is it, your parser isn't filtering all js entries from the HAR? If first is your case, then my second question would be, do your target page has `lazy loading` ?

Comment: Only the js files tagged by <script src="YYYY.js" type="text/javascript"></script> are in the HAR file.  All scripts tagged <script id="XXXX" src="YYYY.js" type="text/javascript"></script> are NOT is the HAR file.  The only difference is the id="XXXX" tag.  These ids are dynamic.  I am asking the developer for more details.